# Calculating Averages Max and Min C++

Tags: c++

```
// Input : Student name, 1 test grade perstudent
// Output: Student Averages, Class Averages, Top Student Last Student

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float CalcAvgClassGrade(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5)

{
    float avg, sum;

    // Sum grades, and get avg
    sum = s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5;
    avg = sum / 2;
    return avg;
}

string  getMax(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5, string n1, string  n2, string n3, string n4, string n5)
{
    float max;
    string maxName;
    // Compares each grade to find the max
    max = s1;
    maxName = n1;
    if (max <  s2)
    {
        max = s2;
        maxName = n2;
    }
    if (max <  s3)
    {
        max = s3;
        maxName = n3;
    }
    if (max <  s4)
    {
        max = s4;
        maxName = n4;
    }
    if (max <  s5)
    {
        max = s5;
        maxName = n5;
    }


    return maxName;

}

string getMin(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5, string n1, string n2, string n3, string n4, string n5) 
{

    float min;
    string minName;
    // Compares each grade to find the min
    min = s1;
    minName = n1;
    if (min <  s2)
    {
        min = s2;
        minName = n2;
    }
    if (min < s3)
    {
        min = s3;
        minName = n3; 
    }
    if (min <   s4);
    { 
        min = s4;
        minName = n4;
    }
    if (min <  s5)
    {
        min = s5;
        minName = n5;
    }
    return minName;

}



int main()
{
    string student1, student2, student3, student4, student5;
    int student1Grade, student2Grade, student3Grade, student4Grade, student5Grade;

    // Enter Student Names;
    cout << "Enter Student Name: ";
    cin >> student1;
    cout << "Enter Student Grade: ";
    cin >> student1Grade;

    cout << "Enter Student Name: ";
    cin >> student2;
    cout << "Enter Student Grade: ";
    cin >> student2Grade;

    cout << "Enter Student Name: ";
    cin >> student3;
    cout << "Enter Student Grade: ";
    cin >> student3Grade;

    cout << "Enter Student Name: ";
    cin >> student4;
    cout << "Enter Student Grade: ";
    cin >> student4Grade;


    cout <<"Enter Student Name : " ;
    cin >> student5;
    cout <<"Enter Student Grade : " ; 
    cin >> student5Grade;
         // Class AVG 
    float classAvg = CalcAvgClassGrade(student1Grade, student2Grade, student3Grade, student4Grade, student5Grade);

    cout << "Class average = " << classAvg; 

        // MAX GRADE 

    string classMax = getMax(student1Grade, student2Grade, student3Grade, student4Grade, student5Grade, student1, student2, student3, student4, student5); 

    cout << classMax << " has the highest grade in the class"; 

        // Min Grade 

    string classMin = getMin(student1Grade, student2Grade, student3Grade, student4Grade, student5Grade, student1, student2, student3, student4, student5); 
    cout << classMin << " has the lowest grade in the class"; 

}
```

This is my first c ++ program. I am having trouble formatting the cout statements , also i think there is some errors in my math because i keep getting a values like 2.56 x e. Any suggestion is appreciated, I have learned alot about syntax so far. I dont think my syntax is correct on the cout statements. Do i need to use endl?

Comment: *I am having trouble formatting the cout statements* You should detail what that trouble is.

Comment: `avg = sum / 2;` -- Are you sure about this calculation?

Comment: Are you familiar with arrays or vectors? When you have similar variable names that only differ by a numerical suffix, then you should definitely use an array or vector.

Comment: There is std::min and std::max({s1, s2, s3, s4, s5})

Answer (score 1):

`if (min < s2)` and other instances of this is wrong. They should be `if (min > s2)`

`avg = sum / 2` is wrong. Should be `avg = sum / 5`

Also have `<< std::endl;` or `<< "\n";` at the end of your last `cout` statement to generate a new line.

Answer (score 1):

You have 5 students, You have to calculate average on 5 students:

```
float CalcAvgClassGrade(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5)
{
    float avg, sum;
    // Sum grades, and get avg
    sum = s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5;
    avg = sum / 5;    //math: average on 5 students
    return avg;
}
```

In `getMin` method you compare grades and `min` wrongly.

> If any number is less than `min`, Take that number as new min

So turn all `<`s to `>` in `getMin` method

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing a bug here:

```
string getMin(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5, string n1, string n2, string n3, string n4, string n5) 
{

    float min;
    string minName;
    // Compares each grade to find the min
    min = s1;
    minName = n1;
    if (min <  s2)
    {
        min = s2;
        minName = n2;
    }
    if (min < s3)
    {
        min = s3;
        minName = n3; 
    }
    if (min <   s4);
    { 
        min = s4;
        minName = n4;
    }
    if (min <  s5)
    {
        min = s5;
        minName = n5;
    }
    return minName;

}
```

You have to use: `>` instead `<`

Comment: @NathanOliver: not given the logic in the if branches.  It currently finds the greatest.